# How to replace the white space in a string in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
    Person_1     Person_2     Person_3 
0   John Smith   Jane Smith   Mark Smith 
1   Harry Jones  Mary Jones   Susan Jones
```

Reproducible form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['John Smith', 'Jane Smith', 'Mark Smith'],
               ['Harry Jones', 'Mary Jones', 'Susan Jones'],
              columns=['Person_1', 'Person_2', 'Person_3'])
```

What is the nicest way to replace the whitespace between the first and last name in each name with an underscore _ to get:

```
    Person_1     Person_2     Person_3 
0   John_Smith   Jane_Smith   Mark_Smith 
1   Harry_Jones  Mary_Jones   Susan_Jones
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 29):

I think you could also just opt for [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).

```
df.replace(' ', '_', regex=True)
```

**Outputs**

```
      Person_1    Person_2     Person_3
0   John_Smith  Jane_Smith   Mark_Smith
1  Harry_Jones  Mary_Jones  Susan_Jones
```

---

From some rough benchmarking, it predictably seems like piRSquared's NumPy solution is indeed the fastest, for this small sample at least, followed by `DataFrame.replace`.

```
%timeit df.values[:] = np.core.defchararray.replace(df.values.astype(str), ' ', '_')
10000 loops, best of 3: 78.4 µs per loop

%timeit df.replace(' ', '_', regex=True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 932 µs per loop

%timeit df.stack().str.replace(' ', '_').unstack()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.29 ms per loop
```

**Interestingly** however, it appears that piRSquared's Pandas solution scales *much* better with larger DataFrames than `DataFrame.replace`, and even outperforms the NumPy solution.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['John Smith', 'Jane Smith', 'Mark Smith']*10000,
                       ['Harry Jones', 'Mary Jones', 'Susan Jones']*10000])
```

```
%timeit df.values[:] = np.core.defchararray.replace(df.values.astype(str), ' ', '_')
10 loops, best of 3: 181 ms per loop

%timeit df.replace(' ', '_', regex=True)
1 loop, best of 3: 4.14 s per loop

%timeit df.stack().str.replace(' ', '_').unstack()
10 loops, best of 3: 99.2 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `replace` method of dataframe:

```
df.replace('\s+', '_',regex=True,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 7):

## `pandas`

`stack` / `unstack` with `str.replace`

```
df.stack().str.replace(' ', '_').unstack()

      Person_1    Person_2     Person_3
0   John_Smith  Jane_Smith   Mark_Smith
1  Harry_Jones  Mary_Jones  Susan_Jones
```

## `numpy`

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.core.defchararray.replace(df.values.astype(str), ' ', '_'),
    df.index, df.columns)

      Person_1    Person_2     Person_3
0   John_Smith  Jane_Smith   Mark_Smith
1  Harry_Jones  Mary_Jones  Susan_Jones
```

---

***time testing***
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I used the below code to replace white spaces in multiple (specific) Columns.

```
df[['Col1','Col2','Col3']] = df[['Col1','col2','Col3']].replace(' ', '', regex=True)
```