# How to replace any number of special characters with a space in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in Pandas that has a number of @ characters in between words. The number of consecutive @ is random and I can't replace them with a single space not blank space since it would create cases such as

| Original string | Replacing with '' | Replacing with '_' or single space |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sun is@@@@yellow | Sun isyellow | Sun is____yellow |

I want to convert the above string into - 'Sun is yellow'

Is there a way to do thisfor the entire string column?

Comment: If there is only one @, do you want to remove it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace the white space in a string in a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462530/how-to-replace-the-white-space-in-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need replace one or multiple `@` to one space use regex `[@]+`:

```
df['New string'] = df['Original string'].replace(r'[@]+', ' ', regex=True)
print (df)
    Original string     New string
0  Sun is@@@@yellow  Sun is yellow
```